# How to force pprint to print one list/tuple/dict element per line?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pretty-print, pprint

How can I force pprint() to print one list/tuple/dict element per line?

```python
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> my_var = ['one', 'two', ('red','green'), {'state' : 'Oregon', 'city' : 'Portland'}]
>>> pprint(my_var)
['one', 'two', ('red', 'green'), {'city': 'Portland', 'state': 'Oregon'}]
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```python
['one',
 'two',
 ('red',
  'green'),
 {'city': 'Portland',
  'state': 'Oregon'}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `width=1` argument to `pprint()`:

```python
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> my_var = ['one', 'two', ('red','green'), {'state' : 'Oregon', 'city' : 'Portland'}]
>>> pprint(my_var, width=1)
['one',
 'two',
 ('red',
  'green'),
 {'city': 'Portland',
  'state': 'Oregon'}]
>>>
```

["pprint - Data pretty printer" documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

Comment: This works well for relatively flat objects but does not work out to one per line for deeply nested objects whereas I'd like to achieve a newline after each opening brace.  For instance, try `pprint`ing `{u'a': {u'b': {u'c': {u'd': {u'foo': 1, u'bar': 2}}}}}`.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston if your dictionary can be json encoded then a quick way to achieve that would be to use: `print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=2))`

Comment: Thanks!  This got me looking at all the pprint options... I'm generating some python code with very large nested dictionaries, and I wanted to be able to print pretty long lines, but wrap them at a width that wouldn't make my IDE (Eclipse) barf.  I used width=4000 and compact=true.  Of course, I wish Eclipse's editor could handle long lines...

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
print(json.dumps(mydict, 
         indent=2).replace('true','True').replace('false','False'))
```

Otherwise, json transforms boolean values to lowercase.  Of course, it doesn't work correctly if these keywords are part of some other string! Then regex replacements can be used.